# After import, Products attributes not showing up in website

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, import, ce-1.8.1.0, csv

Am using magento 1.8.1 version and i have updated Manufacturers for about 400 products via CSV file. The manufacturers value is assigned correctly to their respective products.

But its not showing on the Frontend of the website. Here's a twist. When i OPEN and EDIT the product From admin and SAVE it, and then it shows up on the website in both layered navigation and in additional specs.

I cannot find the source of my problem. Can anyone guide me to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you refresh the indexes via System -> Index management?

Comment: @KennyDs:: Yes i have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you've cleared all the product related indexes and then you'll need to also clear a number of caches. If you have a low traffic site I'd advise you to just clear the entire 'Cache Storage'.

If you're a high traffic website you'll want to try clearing **Blocks HTML output** and **Collections Data**.

If that still didn't work you'll need to verify that the **manufacturer** attribute has **Visible on Product View Page on Front-end** set to yes.

You can do this through Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes and locating the **manufacturer** and making the change. You'll need to clear the caches if this was previously disabled.

Comment: Am doing this in my local environment. I have cleared cache and then done the total reindexing. I have not customized my template. And the front-end is set to YES.

Comment: @Franc which template are you using?

Comment: Its default one.

Comment: Do you import the data from the CSV trough Magento's build in import/export module or have you written your own code ? - By MaxiAxi.com

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I have used the admin panel to import the csv file. NO custom codes. My core files are untouched. The import was successful.

Comment: @Franc : Does solve your problem